# Slide Rule on Shabbos/Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, shabbat, torah-study, technology, mathematics

May a slide rule (mechanical device before calculators) can be used on Shabbos for Gemara calculations?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it is prohibited?

Comment: Lining the gradients together could be a form of Kesiva.

Comment: @SethJ Regarding whether measuring for a generic mitzva is an *uvdin d'chol* problem, see Rambam ([*Hil. Shabbos* 24:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=12&perek=24&halocha=5), ומחשבין חשבונות של מצוה ומודדין מדידה של מצוה). However see Ritva, who prohibits (*Shabbos* 157b, ומסתברא דאפילו מדידה דמצוה לא שרינן אלא כשהיא לצורך השבת, ואע"ג דחשבינן חשבונות של מצוה וכל הנהו דפרק שואל (לעיל ק"נ א'), התם דיבור והלוך בעלמא הוא דשרי אבל לעשות מעשה משקל ומדה לית לן בה למשרי כיון דאפשר ליה לאחר השבת). I think there's reasonable basis for asking whether this applies to a slide rule.

Comment: ... Also whether studying gemara on Shabbos is considered לצורך השבת even according to the Ritva.

Comment: I pondered about measuring.  But measuring and calculating/counting are not the same.

Comment: @user4500 I'm not certain that's true from the standpoint of *hilchos Shabbos*.

Comment: @Fred, I thought about calculating as measuring, too. But it's not obvious in the question.